# How to add newly updated dynamic values in state to old object in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, dynamic, state

I am creating a CRUD app in Java + React.js. I want to update user information, I am populating a dynamic form based on the employeeDetails array. On a result I am getting dynamically updated values from user in state. But I am not sure how to add those new input values from the form to old object, and update it to and send it to backend. Thanks in advance your help is appreciated.

I tried doing this.setState() after submitting form, to update old object with new values.

State of react app:

```
state = {
    employeeDetails: ['Name', 'Gender', 'Education', 'Address', 'Mobile Number', 'Experience'],
    editEmployee: {
     Name: "Rohan",
     Gender: 23,
     Education: "Software Engineer",
     Mobile Number: 12345,
     Experience: "Fresher"
    }
  }
```

Dynamic form of update user:

```
<form onSubmit={props.updateEmployee}>
   {
     Object.keys(props.editEmployee).map(details => <Fragment key={details}>
         <label>{details}</label><br />
         <input type="text" name={details} onChange={props.handleChange} defaultValue={props.editEmployee[details]} />
 </Fragment>
)}
```

Update method:

```
updateEmployee = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
    editEmployee: {...this.state.editEmployee, dynamic value}
    })
    axios.put("http://localhost:9450/updateEmployee", this.state.editEmployee)
      .then(res => console.log(res))
      .then(this.setState({
        editEmployee: ''
      }))
  }
```

I want the newly updated values in my editEmployee object which I will send to backend server to update the user information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, assuming that your Form is another separate component.

```
const Form = (props) => (
  <form onSubmit={props.updateEmployee}>
    {Object.keys(props.editEmployee).map((details) => (
      <React.Fragment key={details}>
        <label>{details}</label><br />
        <input type="text" name={details} onChange={props.handleChange} defaultValue={props.editEmployee[details]} />
      </React.Fragment>
    ))}
  </form>
);
```

In your parent container you have state and methods

```
state = {
  employeeDetails: ['Name', 'Gender', 'Education', 'Address', 'Mobile Number', 'Experience'],
  editEmployee: {
    Name: "Rohan",
    Gender: 23,
    Education: "Software Engineer",
    'Mobile Number': 12345,
    Experience: "Fresher"
  }
}

handleChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({
    editEmployee: {
      ...this.state.editEmployee,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    },
  })
}

updateEmployee = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  axios.put("http://localhost:9450/updateEmployee", this.state.editEmployee)
    .then(res => console.log(res))
}
```

Your `handleChange` should update the state values and you don't have to call `setState` during your form submission. You should already have the latest changes in your state when you call `updateEmployee`

Comment: Can you mark my answer as the correct answer? Thanks !